# Propper way of URL building on Flask

Tags: python, flask

I want to have url like this `/csv/table` and I have it, but it doesn't work, give me an error

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL was not found on the server. If you
>   entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Here is pug code for upload form

```
form(method='post' action="{{ url_for('table', root=url_for('upload')) }}"
```

and flask routes

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/csv/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    return render_template('upload.html')

@app.route('/<root>table', methods=['POST'])
def table(root):
    return render_template('table.html', root=root)
```

Comment: are you not missing a slash in `@app.route('/<root>table', methods=['POST'])` so the route is `/<root>/table` ?

Comment: I mean you have a `/csv/` route and `/<something>table/` route but not a `/<something>/table` which you are trying to get to by `/csv/table`

Comment: @reportgunner: are you not missing a slash ---

no, `/csv/` already have it, also `/csv` not wokring

Comment: overall in browser I have popper url, hm.. you mean route cant find it, so I have to fix `/csv/` ok I'll try

Answer (score 1):

thanks @reportgunner =)

problem was in `/csv/` route and button for my second page `a(href blah-blah-blah`

I created propper form with action and now all works fine

except first level url, which is have trailing question mark now `http://127.0.0.1:5000/csv?` heh